# Rails 3 getting gmail contacts using omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, omniauth

I am successfully login with google credentials using omniauth? omniauth is providing uid as following link

https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=xxxxxxxxxx

by using the above link is possible to get gmail contacts or their any other way to get gmail contact

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Omniauth just provides authentication.

There is a gem that might be interesting for you: https://github.com/cardmagic/contacts

Quote: "Contacts is a universal interface to grab contact list information from various providers including Hotmail, AOL, Gmail, Plaxo and Yahoo."

Edit: Take a look at this blog post too: http://rtdptech.com/2010/12/importing-gmail-contacts-list-to-rails-application/

Answer (score 5):

Get your client_id and client_secret from [here](https://code.google.com/apis/console/). This is rough script, which works perfectly fine. Modified it as per your needs.

```
    require 'net/http'
    require 'net/https'
    require 'uri'
    require 'rexml/document'

    class ImportController < ApplicationController

      def authenticate
        @title = "Google Authetication"

        client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        google_root_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?state=profile&redirect_uri="+googleauth_url+"&response_type=code&client_id="+client_id.to_s+"&approval_prompt=force&scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/"
        redirect_to google_root_url
      end

      def authorise
        begin
          @title = "Google Authetication"
          token = params[:code]
          client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
          client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          uri = URI('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
          http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
          http.use_ssl = true
          http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
          request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)

          request.set_form_data('code' => token, 'client_id' => client_id, 'client_secret' => client_secret, 'redirect_uri' => googleauth_url, 'grant_type' => 'authorization_code')
          request.content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          response = http.request(request)
          response.code
          access_keys = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body)

          uri = URI.parse("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?oauth_token="+access_keys['access_token'].to_s+"&max-results=50000&alt=json")

          http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
          http.use_ssl = true
          http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
          request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
          response = http.request(request)
          contacts = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body)
          contacts['feed']['entry'].each_with_index do |contact,index|

             name = contact['title']['$t']
             contact['gd$email'].to_a.each do |email|
              email_address = email['address']
              Invite.create(:full_name => name, :email => email_address, :invite_source => "Gmail", :user_id => current_user.id)  # for testing i m pushing it into database..
            end

          end  
        rescue Exception => ex
           ex.message
        end
        redirect_to root_path , :notice => "Invite or follow your Google contacts."


      end

    end
```

Screenshot for settings.

[image]

Comment: MultiJson::LoadError (795: unexpected token at '<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Error
401
(Client Error)