# Requesting Google Contacts in Ruby using Omniauth

Tags: ruby, oauth, contacts, omniauth

I have successfully authenticated against Google using Omniauth, and now have session token and secret in my Authentication record, with :scope => "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/".

I can't figure out how to get access to the user's contacts list using these credentials rather than asking the user for a password.

Is there a Gem for doing this? I tried gdata, but am still stuck figuring out what method to use to request the contact feed, and how to supply the token information. Anyone has dealt with this before and can help me out?

Comment: It will help a lot for you to show code you've written. Without that we're just guessing.

Comment: well..truth is I have not written any code other than the standard omniauth declarations in omniauth.rb. (provider :google,   Google_client_id, Google_client_secret  , {:scope => "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/"} ). The user is redirected to the google page and then back to the app, the the tokens are assigned. I just don't know how to request the contacts feed. I have tried a few approaches in the irb console without much success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646547/rails-3-getting-gmail-contacts-using-omniauth). The authentication will be handled by OmniAuth, so you can essentially skip down to the contacts request.